# Change upsell.phtml in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

I have site - magento 1.9.2 . Upsells products are vizualizate аs slideshow, i want to sort them in four columns and show them in a few lines no matter how many. I don't want to have a slide show. I tried another code, but could not visualize the products in more than one row, i want to get this:

[image]

```
<?php if($itemNum = count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>
<?php $_grhelper =  Mage::helper('granada');?>
<div class="box-collateral products-list-slider box-up-sell">
    <h2 class="slider-title secondary-font"><?php echo $this->__('Още серии бани - избери /тук ще са отделните серии') ?></h2>
    <div class="products-grid" id="upsell-product-table">
    <?php // $this->setColumnCount(5); // uncomment this line if you want to have another number of columns. also can be changed in layout ?>
    <?php $this->resetItemsIterator() ?>
    <?php for($_i=0;$_i<$itemNum;$_i++): ?>
        <?php if($_link=$this->getIterableItem()): ?>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_link->getId()); ?>
                <?php

                // Get the Special Price
                $specialprice = $product->getFinalPrice();
                $orgprice = $product->getPrice();
                // Get the Special Price FROM date
                $specialPriceFromDate = $product->getSpecialFromDate();
                // Get the Special Price TO date
                $specialPriceToDate = $product->getSpecialToDate();
                // Get Current date
                $today =  time();
                $is_special = 0;
                if ($specialprice<$orgprice){
                    $save_percent = 100-round(($specialprice/$orgprice)*100);
                    if($today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)){
                        if(Mage::getStoreConfig("granada_setting/product_label/sale", $code)){
                            ?>
                            <?php $is_special = 1; ?>
                            <span class="label-icon sale-label"><?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig("granada_setting/product_label/sale_label_type", $code)): ?><?php echo "-".$save_percent."%"; ?><?php else: ?><?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig("granada_setting/product_label/sale_txt", $code) ?><?php endif; ?></span>
                        <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <?php
                $now = date("Y-m-d");
                $newsFrom= substr($_link->getData('news_from_date'),0,10);
                $newsTo=  substr($_link->getData('news_to_date'),0,10);
                if ($newsTo != '' || $newsFrom != ''){
                    if (($newsTo != '' && $newsFrom != '' && $now>=$newsFrom && $now<=$newsTo) || ($newsTo == '' && $now >=$newsFrom) || ($newsFrom == '' && $now<=$newsTo))
                    {
                        if(Mage::getStoreConfig("granada_setting/product_label/new", $code)){
                            ?>
                            <?php if ($is_special): ?>
                                <span class="label-icon new-label second-label"><?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig("granada_setting/product_label/new_txt", $code) ?></span>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <span class="label-icon new-label"><?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig("granada_setting/product_label/new_txt", $code) ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <?php
                $effect = $_grhelper->getEffect();
                ?>
                <?php if ($effect == 'no'): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_link, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image no-effect">
                        <?php if ($_grhelper->isKeepRatio()):?>
                            <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_link,'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(350); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_link, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php $imgWidth = $_grhelper->getImgWidth(); ?>
                            <?php $imgHeight = $_grhelper->getImgHeight(); ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_link,'small_image')->resize($imgWidth, $imgHeight); ?>" width="<?php echo $imgWidth ?>" height="<?php echo $imgHeight ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_link, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                <?php elseif ($effect == 'alt_img'): ?>
                    <?php
                    $product = $_link->load('media_gallery');
                    $productMediaGallery = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
                    $altImg = $productMediaGallery->getItemByColumnValue($_grhelper->getAltCol(), $_grhelper->getAltColVal());
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_link, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image alt-image-effect">
                        <?php if ($_grhelper->isKeepRatio()):?>
                            <img class="cat-main-img" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_link,'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(350); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_link, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                            <?php if ($altImg): ?>
                                <?php if($altImg->getFile()): ?>
                                    <img class="alt-image" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_link,'small_image',$altImg->getFile())->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(350)?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_link, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php $imgWidth = $_grhelper->getImgWidth(); ?>
                            <?php $imgHeight = $_grhelper->getImgHeight(); ?>
                            <img class="cat-main-img" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_link,'small_image')->resize($imgWidth, $imgHeight); ?>" width="<?php echo $imgWidth ?>" height="<?php echo $imgHeight ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_link, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                            <?php if ($altImg): ?>
                                <?php if($altImg->getFile()): ?>
                                    <img class="alt-image" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_link,'small_image',$altImg->getFile())->resize($imgWidth, $imgHeight); ?>" width="<?php echo $imgWidth ?>" height="<?php echo $imgHeight ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_link, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                <?php elseif ($effect == 'listed_img'): ?>
                    <?php
                    $imgList = '';
                    $product = $_link->load('media_gallery');
                    foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
                        // If no image, skip
                        if ($image->getFile() == NULL)
                            continue;
                        if ($_grhelper->isKeepRatio()) {
                            $imgList .= Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_link,'small_image',$image->getFile())->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(350).',';
                        } else {
                            $imgWidth = $_grhelper->getImgWidth();
                            $imgHeight = $_grhelper->getImgHeight();
                            $imgList .= Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_link,'small_image',$image->getFile())->resize($imgWidth, $imgHeight).',';
                        }
                    }
                    $imgList = substr($imgList, 0, strlen($imgList) - 1);
                    ?>
                    <div class="list-image-effect">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_link, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image" data-images-list="<?php echo $imgList; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php if($_grhelper->isKeepRatio()):?><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(350); ?><?php else: ?><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'small_image')->resize($_grhelper->getImgWidth(), $_grhelper->getImgHeight()); ?><?php endif; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_link, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="actions">
                    <div class="actions-wrapper">
                        <?php if($_link->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart product-add-btn" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_link) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></a>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_link) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" class="link-wishlist product-btn"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_link)): ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>" class="link-compare product-btn"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_link, true) ?>
            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?></a></h2>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        jQuery('.box-up-sell .products-grid').owlCarousel({
            responsive: {
                0:{
                    items: 1
                },
                479:{
                    items: 2
                },
                768: {
                    items: 3
                },
                1199: {
                    items: 4
                }
            },
            lazyLoad: true,
            pagination: false,
            navigation: true
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```